# Link with triangle at the end of the box

Tags: css, geometry, css-shapes

I have been fiddling around with making a link that would have a css class on it. When that class is added it adds a blue background behind it and adds a triangle to the end of the background width. Problem is i can seem to figure out why it wont line up properly. I have tried floats and different display settings.

My question is how can I make a link have a background behind it and then add a triangle at the end of the link background. Also if you have any other suggestion about how im doing this that would be appreciated as well.

I have set up a jsfiddle with my working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/L35basmc/

HTML:

```
<a href="features.php" class="sidebar-linebreak-active"><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-lg"></i> Feature Highlights</a><div class="sidebar-linebreak-active-arrow"></div>
<a href="create-your-store.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-building fa-lg"></i> Create your store</a>
<a href="configure-your-products.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-money fa-lg"></i> Configure your products</a>
<a href="manage-your-store.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i> Manage your store</a>
<a href="rank-high-in-search.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-lg"></i> Rank high in search</a>
<a href="marketing.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Marketing</a>
<a href="conversion-tools.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"></i> Conversion tools</a>
<a href="hosting-and-security.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-lg"></i> Hosting & security</a>
<a href="analytics.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-database fa-lg"></i> Analytics</a>
<a href="apps-and-integration.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-lg"></i> Apps & integrations</a>
<a href="expert-support.php" class="sidebar-linebreak"><i class="fa fa-umbrella fa-lg"></i> Expert support</a>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar-linebreak {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: #53c6f3;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-linebreak:hover {
    color: #1a9ec6;
}

.sidebar-linebreak-active, sidebar-linebreak-active:hover {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #1a9ec6;
}

.sidebar-linebreak-active-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #1a9ec6;
}

.sidebar-linebreak-active-arrow:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a background of width:100% and then adding the arrow, so that's why the arrow falls.

Set a smaller width for your background say 90% -

```
.sidebar-linebreak-active, sidebar-linebreak-active:hover {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    width: 90%; /* <-- */
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #1a9ec6;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/L35basmc/18/)**

Comment: That works very well. Didn't think that the width would even be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is your friend here.
Add `position:relative;` to your link and use `:after` on the link to create the arrow. Then you can ditch the empty div and you don't need to mess with floats.

```
.sidebar-linebreak {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: #53c6f3;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-linebreak:hover {
    color: #1a9ec6;
}

.sidebar-linebreak-active, sidebar-linebreak-active:hover {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #1a9ec6;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar-linebreak-active:after{
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
    border-left: 20px solid #1a9ec6;
    position: absolute;
    top:-2px;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L35basmc/17/

You may need to adjust your border widths and or the positioning of the arrow to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

in your sidebar-linebreak class you can have the wanted results in one step. You can add left padding and add the image to the background in front of the color, it would be along the lines of

```
.sidebar-linebreak{
 //Your other code
    display:block;
    padding-left:15px;
    background:url("ImageLocation/triangleImage.png") #1a9ec6 no-repeat;
    background-size:15px;
    background-position:left;

}
```

If you want it at the right, simply add the padding to the right and position the image to the right instead of left